# Paint Light Bulbs

Tags: lighting, paint

I am looking for paint that can achieve this effect any ideas?:
[image]
https://www.etsy.com/de/listing/58341079/hand-painted-rainbow-mood-light-bulb-4?ref=listing-shop-header-2

Comment: There are "stained glass" paints intended for glass. The question is going to be which of them can handle the temperature the bulb will reach.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Link-centered questions are discouraged, as they suffer from link rot. It would be best to edit in the image of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: The question is off-topic as a product recommendation request anyway. Voted to close.

Comment: Very '60's. I like it. Then again I have a non-ironic lava lamp so my judgement is questionable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related products are commonly called bulb dipping paint for example:

They do make [light bulb paint](http://www.conrad.com/ce/en/overview/1201031/Light-Bulb-Paint) my mom used to make some directly on the bulb but then when it burns out the design is lost. This looks like a clear shade that was painted, I always thought that was better so you could rotate the fixture and the rainbow , Christmas tree , hearts, or bunny were centered on the wall she had / has a different shade for every season.

Comment: I decided to use a Round-bottom flask with a halogen bulb inside to make it last longer.

Answer (score 0):

if you use an incandescent, i cant offer any suggestion as i dont know of any.  however, if you go to led, surface temp is lower, and almost any paint would work.  just thin it with clear coat to get the transparency effect